# How to start a activity indicator in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am displaying on a view a  activity indicator but somehow the indicator is not spinning why so ever

```
func activityPanelOn(on: Bool){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations:  {() in
        self.acPanel.alpha = (on) ? 0.6 : 0.0
        }, completion:{(finished: Bool)  in
            if(finished){
                self.acPanel.hidden = !on
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start animating a `UIAcitivityIndicatorView` , simply call `activityIndicatior.startAnimating()`.

Answer (score 1):

use this - `actInd.startAnimating()` to start the activity indicator.

```
var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
actInd.center = self.view.center
actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
view.addSubview(actInd)
actInd.startAnimating()
```

& use this code to stop it:

```
actInd.stopAnimating()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call a method for spinning,if `self.acPanel` activity indiactor
then call

`self.acPanel.startAnimating()`